# Webpack exclude file (not folder)

Tags: webpack

I tried to exclude a file in my webpack but it is not working. I don't want it to be compiled together app.js I want it in a separate file. I read that for webpack it's not posible to compile in diferent files, but you can exclude them. So I wanted to exclude it and then compile with typescript.

The problem is that that file has variables used from other files, I don't know if the problem is this.

I have:

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: './src/app/shared/config.ts',
        loader: 'ts'
    },
```

I thought that maybe adding it to entries it can work, but as I read you can't, I discarted that posibility. Now I have at entries:

```
entry: {
    polyfills: './src/polyfills.ts',
    vendor: './src/vendor.ts',
    app: './src/main.ts'
},
```

Comment: would you show your output section?

Comment: Ok but I discarted this option as I think is imposible. I did a json file with configurations that I read when you login.
    `output: {
        path: helpers.root('www'),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },`

Answer (score 0):

From the official [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders):

> A condition may be a RegExp (tested against absolute path), a string containing the absolute path, a function(absPath): bool, or an array of one of these combined with “and”.

You're setting `exclude` with a string (as it's quoted) so it should contain the absolute path of the file you want to exclude (you're using relative path)

Try setting it with the absolute path or use a regex `exclude: /src\/app\/shared\/config\.ts/`

Comment: I can't make it works. I tried:
`exclude: helpers.root('./src/app/shared/config.ts'),`
and
`exclude: helpers.root('/src\/app\/shared\/config\.ts/'),`
As I have (not made by me) an example here:
`exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),`
I wish there will be a better manual for webpack u.u

Comment: Ok I found where I tootk the example `exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app')` from [angular documentation webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)

Comment: Try doing: `exclude: path.join(__dirname, 'src/app/shared/config.ts')`. You might need to add `const path = require('path')` at the top of the file (webpack.config.js) if it's not there already.

Comment: I finally made it works. Now I'm facing other problem with exclude: (You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file) but seems finally it reads the file I wrote: `helpers.root('src/app/shared/config.ts')` I just needed to ommit the ./ from the path

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work at all. I think it's imposible to do what I want because config.ts is imported in other ts files. Even if I write to exclude it, it isn't excluded.

Comment: If you have other loaders that can read .ts files, then chances are that it's being imported there. If you post your entire webpack config, we might give you better answers :)

Comment: No I don't have other ts loaders. I have imports of that class in other ts. For example:
`import {Config} from "../shared/config"` in page.component.ts
I think there is no way of doing this. I will put the config information in a file and then read the file with Filereader.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding a specific absolute path instead of using a regular expression, like this:

```
{
    test: /\.(gif|jpg|png|svg|ttf|eot|woff|otf)$/,//(png|jpg|gif|svg)
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        name: '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]'
    },
    exclude:  [path.join(projectRoot, './vue/img')]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem, as I wrote, is that the file I'm trying to exclude is IMPORTED in other files, so even if I try to exclude it, I think It's not posible. So I changed it to a json file and excluded it and it worked. I would like to close this question but I don't know if it's posible to do without marking a valid answer. And I would like to leave this question to help people who would have the same problem when trying to exclude imported ts.